# function is not a function - react-native

Tags: react-native

In my project, I used stack navigator as the navigator. Inside navigationOptions, at headerRight, I used a custom button. When I try to call the onPress, it says the function is not a function.

this is the function

```
  sharePost() {
    // this.props.doShare();
    console.log("DONE");
  }
```

I have put the full code here. I want to use sharePost function inside the rightHeader of navigationOptions.

```
     import React, { Component } from "react";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Animated,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";

import { PostProfileBar, WritePost } from "../../components";
import { ButtonWithoutBackground } from "../../mixing/UI";

const width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const height = Dimensions.get("window").height / 3;

class SharePostScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  sharePost() {
    // this.props.doShare();
    console.log("DONE");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <WritePost profile={this.state.loggedUserProfile} />

          <View style={styles.sharePostWrapper}>
            <PostProfileBar profile={this.state.postedUserProfile} />

            <Image
              source={{
                uri: "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DWvRLbBVoAA4CCM.jpg"
              }}
              resizeMode={"stretch"}
              style={styles.image}
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitle: "Share To Feed",
    headerTitleStyle: {
      paddingLeft: "20%",
      paddingRight: "20%"
    },
    headerStyle: {
      paddingRight: 10,
      paddingLeft: 10
    },
    headerLeft: (
      <Icon
        name={"close"}
        size={30}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.goBack();
        }}
      />
    ),
    headerRight: (
      <ButtonWithoutBackground
        buttonText={styles.buttonText}
        onPress={this.sharePost()}
      >
        Post
      </ButtonWithoutBackground>
    )
  });
}
```

Comment: Where is the `sharePost()` defined, is it a `class method` or a `global one` ?

Comment: it is a class method. defined before the render()

Comment: If it's a `class method` you cannot call it directly from the `static methods`, since `this` reference is not valid.

Comment: I put the full code. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to call the `class level methods` inside the `static` method `navigationOptions`, you can do the following,

```
// Bind function using setParams

componentDidMount() {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  navigation.setParams({
    referencedSharePost: this.sharePost,
  });
}

sharePost = (parameters) => {
    // this.props.doShare();
    console.log("DONE" + parameters);
  }

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
  return {
     //... Other Options
     headerRight: (
      <ButtonWithoutBackground
        buttonText={styles.buttonText}
        onPress={() => params.referencedSharePost("I'm passing something")}
      >
        Post
      </ButtonWithoutBackground>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this, pardon for any typos

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks Pritish. So the issue was, I was trying to use a class function inside static one right?

Comment: Yes, you can't reference a function from `static methods` to class ones, you need to either instantiate `class methods` as `static`, but `React` doesn't encourage that, therefore other workaround is to use the `props` of navigation, the last one is to make a component and bind it using `redux`

Comment: Thanks again for saving my time bro.

Comment: Hi Pritish. I posted another question similar to this. Could you please give an answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024361/calling-a-redux-action-using-props-from-stack-navigator-options