# Calling a redux action using props, from stack-navigator-options

Tags: react-native

I want to call an action from redux inside the stack navigator options. This is my code. When I use the action using this.props.action_name, it says this is not a function. What am I doing wrong here? I used the navigation.params to achieve this, but still it doesn't work.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      referencedSharePost: this.sharePost,
      referencedDoShare: this.props.doShare
    });
  }

  sharePost = () => {
    this.props.doShare();
    console.log("DONE");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <WritePost profile={this.state.loggedUserProfile} />

          <View style={styles.sharePostWrapper}>
            <PostProfileBar profile={this.state.postedUserProfile} />

            <Image
              source={{
                uri: "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DWvRLbBVoAA4CCM.jpg"
              }}
              resizeMode={"stretch"}
              style={styles.image}
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;

    return {
      headerTitle: "Share To Feed",
      headerTitleStyle: {
        paddingLeft: "20%",
        paddingRight: "20%"
      },
      headerStyle: {
        paddingRight: 10,
        paddingLeft: 10
      },
      headerLeft: (
        <Icon
          name={"close"}
          size={30}
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.goBack();
          }}
        />
      ),
      headerRight: (
        <ButtonWithoutBackground
          buttonText={styles.buttonText}
          onPress={() => params.referencedSharePost()}
        >
          Post
        </ButtonWithoutBackground>
      )
    };
  };
```

This is how I map my state to props.

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

import SharePostScreen from "./SharePostScreen";
import { doShare } from "../../config/actions";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    sharedPost: state.mainFeed.updatedPost
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    doShare: bindActionCreators(doShare, dispatch)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SharePostScreen);
```

I want to use this.props.doShare inside onPress() of stackNavigationOptions.

Comment: Can you add the code how you're binding redux props to the screen, and also where do you need to access it?

Comment: I added the additional code Pritish.

Comment: Try `doShare: (params) => console.log(params)` and pass something in `this.props.doShare('Test);`, the rest of the code seems correct.

Comment: I tried it pritish. Didn't work. Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to separately `connect` `SharePostScreen` after exporting it as a default, since it has got no instance to the redux states, during the time component's execution happens.

Therefore you can move your code in the second snippet, to the `SharePostScreen` and use it there, to have an access to the `props`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    sharedPost: state.mainFeed.updatedPost
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    doShare: bindActionCreators(doShare, dispatch)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SharePostScreen);
```

Comment: Worked again. Thanks a lot bro.